# Problem with updating an already updated html dom with Flask

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I have a flask dropzone to upload files.
Once an upload is done I want to print a log text on the html site
It works so far, the only problem is - the div tag doesn't update the log text after the second upload. The website stays with the text from the first upload.

index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
  window.setInterval(function() {
  loadNewLogger()
}, 500)

function loadNewLogger(){

  $.ajax({
    url:"/write_log",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $(logger).replaceWith(data)
    }
  });
}
});


</script>
<body>
    <div style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);text-align:center">
    CDR PIPELINE </div>

  {{ dropzone.create(action='upload') }}
  {{ dropzone.load_js() }}
  {{ dropzone.config() }}


  <div id="logger">
    {{ logger }}
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

logger.html (otherwise I would render index.html twice)

```
  <div id="logger">
    {{ logger }}
  </div>
```

excerpt from flask_app.py:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])

def upload():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'],f.filename))
        upload.logger = ""
        es.main()

        upload.logger = es.main.result

        return upload.logger


    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/write_log',methods=['POST'])

def log():

    logger = upload.logger
    return jsonify('', render_template('logger.html', logger=logger))
```

Why is it updating the text from `upload.logger` only once?

Comment: What is `$(logger)` here ?

Comment: div id="logger"

Comment: Did you check if the ajax request execute or not ? Put console inside your success function see if it gets printed on every interval.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of JQuery AJAX, I would recommend using PHP. For example, when you upload files from index.html you can redirect to upload.php, and you can display the message using "echo"
But even if you aren't comfortable with that, don't get too much into Python or JQuery. Your problem can very easily be solved with plain JavaScript:

Here is your html element in logger.html:

```
<div id="logger"></div>
```

In flask app.py:

```
document.getElementById("logger").innerHTML="Your message to be displayed"
```

I would also recommend you to remove setinterval in index.html as people don't like dynamically reloading blocks

Comment: why should the `document.getElementById` go to flask_app.py? I've replace the `{{ logger }}`in the div in the index.html for `document.getElementById...`. It updates once, but not the second time. Same problem. The setinterval is fine because we won't use it public